# Test for English only A-Z upper case of a character

Tags: java, uppercase

I need to test a character for uppercase only A-Z. Not any other special unicode or other languages.

I was reading the documentation for [Character.isUpperCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase%28char%29). It seems like it would pass if it was a unicode character that was considered uppercase but not technically between A-Z. And it seems like it would pass uppercase characters from other languages besides english.

Do i just need to use regular expressions or am i reading into [Character.isUpperCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase%28char%29) incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, better use a regex.

Comment: Can't you just use the character codes from the char code of `'A'` to `'Z'` to determine if the character is inbetween?

Comment: Try using the ASCII code or a regex.

Comment: I was trying to avoid "re-inventing" the wheel. I was hoping that java already offered this functionality without using regular expressions or character codes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the documentation you linked:

> Many other Unicode characters are uppercase too.

So yes, using `isUpperCase` will match things other than A-Z.
One way to do the test though is like this.

```
boolean isUpperCaseEnglish(char c){
    return c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`isUpperCase` indeed does not promise the character is between `'A'` and `'Z'`. You could use a regex:

```
String s = ...;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
boolean matches = m.matches();
```

Comment: The question is about matching only one character. Wouldn't the regex be only "[A-Z]"? (but I think regex is a little overkill for the purpose of the question)

Answer (score 0):

[`Character.isUpperCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase%28char%29) does accept things based off of other languages.  For instance, `Ω` would be considered uppercase.

But you can do a check to make sure it is between `A` and `Z`:

```
public static boolean isUpperCaseInEnglish(char c) {
     return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
}
```